# equality index of attribute "privateEmail" disallowed

Tags: openldap

I'm installed OpenLDAP 2.4 to CentOS 6 server.
Added custom attributes and schema 'myUser':

```
dn: cn=my,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: my
objectClass: top
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.1 NAME 'firstName' DESC 'First name of a person' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15)
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.2 NAME 'privateEmail' DESC 'Private email of a person' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.41 X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.3 NAME 'userOid' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.339.4 NAME 'isTrusted' DESC 'Determines if user is trusted' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.6 NAME 'gender' DESC 'Person gender (M,F or U)' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.8 NAME 'privatePhone' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.9 NAME 'otpContact' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.10 NAME 'otpAuthnFlag' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.11 NAME 'lastName' DESC 'Last name of a person' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.610 NAME 'nsAccountLock' DESC 'Operational attribute for Account Inactivation' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: ( 331.332.333.12 NAME 'myUser' DESC 'user for my entity' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( uid $ isTrusted $ nsAccountLock $ firstName ) MAY ( lastName $ userPassword $ privateEmail $ otpContact $ otpAuthnFlag $ privatePhone $ userOid ) X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )
```

Trying to add the index and get the error:

```
# ldapadd -x -W -D cn=config -f /opt/index.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}bdb, cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: equality index of attribute "privateEmail" disallowed
```

My index.ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb, cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: privateEmail eq
olcDbIndex: privatePhone eq
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax OID for `privateEmail`. The one you're using is for Postal Addresses, and it doesn't support indexing. [See RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-3.3.28).

You should be using 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 as per [RFC 2798](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2798.txt). Check the others for sanity as well.

Comment: I updated my ldif for created attributes and schema:
`olcAttributeTypes: ( 331.332.333.2 NAME 'privateEmail' DESC 'Private email of a person' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 X-ORIGIN 'user defined' )`
Stoped slapd, removed /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={12}my.ldif, and created the schema and attributes again, but the error `equality index of attribute "privateEmail" disallowed` persist (((
However the attributes privatePhone with the error too

Comment: Well for `privatePhone` you should be using [RFC 4571 Telephone Number](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4517#section-3.3.31). If you have any entries already containing these attributes you will have to at least clear those attributes for the schema change, maybe delete the entries altogether. It would also be worth checking whether your brute-force method of changing the schema has actually taken effect. You should be doing that via `ldapmodify` as per your original question.